# Is a closed and bounded subset of any complete metric space compact?

Tags: metric-spaces

We know that every closed and bounded subset of $\Bbb{R}$ is compact. The proof proceeds by bifurcating $[a,b]$, and then using the property that in a complete metric space the infinite intersection of closed and bounded sets contains one point.

I was wondering if this can be extended to any complete metric space. **Is a closed and bounded set of any complete metric space compact?** If one were to extrapolate the proof given above for this situation, how do you bifurcate a complete metric space?

Also, assume that the complete metric space is ordered. Can you still bifurcate it? How do you find the mid-point?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320619/closed-bounded-but-not-compact-subset-of-a-normed-vector-space). Additionally, what does it mean to be an "ordered metric space"? Is the order in some way compatible with the metric? If so, how? If not, then (by the [Order-Extension Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordering_principle#Order-extension_principle)), we can always order a metric space, and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 33):

Let $X$ be an infinite set. Define a metric $d$ on $X$ by $d(x,y) = 0$ if $x = y$, and $d(x,y) = 1$ if $x \neq y$. This is known as the [discrete metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space). This metric makes $X$ a complete metric space.

Let $E$ be any infinite subset of $X$. Then $E$ is closed and bounded, but not compact.

**Remark:** If we assume in addition that the set is *totally bounded*, the usual proof can be carried out.
Therefore closed and bounded subset of a complete metric space need not be compact.

Comment: So. Much. Simpler. Big ol' +1 from me.

Answer (score 9):

André’s example is probably the simplest; here’s a fairly general technique for constructing such examples. If $\langle X,d\rangle$ is any metric space, the function

$$d\,':X\times X\to\Bbb R:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto\min\{d(x,y),1\}$$

is a metric on $X$ that generates the same topology as $d$. If $\langle X,d\rangle$ is complete but not compact, $\langle X,d\,'\rangle$ provides a counterexample: every subset of $X$ is $d\,'$-bounded, so $X$ is a closed, bounded subset that is not compact. Since $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric is complete but not compact, it provides one such example.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan might also find these Wikipedia links useful: [Totally bounded space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space) & [Montel space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel_space).