# Proving a continuous function is bounded above on a closed interval

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity

I am struggling to understand a step From Angel De La Fuente's book.

Thereom 6.22:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy408.jpg)
The yellow bits are giving me some grief.

The first highlight - is this just by assumption of $f$'s unboundedness? I can always find some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for some $x_n \in [a,b]$, $f(x_n) > n$ ?

Is the second highlighted bit seems to be applying the same logic?

Thanks

Comment: The interval would need to be closed **and** bounded.

Comment: The first point is using the unboundedness as you suggested to construct a sequence $(x_n)_n$ with $f(x_n) \geq n$. The second point is just using the fact that $(x_{n_k})_k$ is a subsequence of $(x_n)$ and there fore $f(x_{n_k}) \geq n_k$. But note that $n_k \geq k$ (the strict inequality might be a typo).

Comment: They are assuming that $f$ is unbounded, so either $f$ is unbounded above or below. They assume above for definiteness. The second is different. Since the $x_n \in [a,b]$, Bolzano-Weierstrass says there is a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$.

Comment: Since $[a, b]$ is a closed, bounded set of reals, it is compact and also sequentially compact. Hence, every sequence in this set admits a convergent subsequence. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3381175/a-closed-bounded-set-of-a-complete-metric-space-can-fail-to-be-compact

Comment: not that you could always find *some* $n$: It is that for *every* $n$ you could find $x_n$ with $f(x_n)>n$, assuming $f$ is not bounded above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your first question, yes, this is because of the unboundedness assumption. If no such $x_n$ existed for some $n \in \Bbb{N}$, then this would imply that $f(x) < n$ for all $x \in [a, b]$, which is to say $f$ is bounded above by $n$.

In answer to your second question, this follows from the first highlight. You know that $f(x_n) \ge n$ for all $n$, so $f(x_{n_k}) \ge n_k$ for all $k$. Now, here the proof makes a small, inconsequential error: it really should claim $n_k \ge k$, rather than $n_k > k$. This is due to the nature of subsequences; the sequence $n_k$ must be a sequence of natural numbers that is *strictly increasing*, and a simple induction proof shows $n_k \ge k$ for all $k$.

Comment: Ah, ofcourse! So, just to make sure I understand.

If I have the following sequence:

$(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, ... )$ where $ n = 1, 2, 3, ...$
a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ could be every second $x$, eg. $(x_2, x_4, ...)$ so obviously, if $k=1$, then the subsequence $n_k=2$ - is that correct/

Comment: yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n$ be a sequence such that $|f(x_n)| \to \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)|$.

Bolzano Weierstrass gives a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ that converges to some $x^* \in [a,b]$.

Since $|f|$ is continuous, we have $|f(x_{n_k})| \to |f(x^*)|$ and hence $|f(x^*)| = \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)|$.

In particular, $f$ is bounded.