# Compactness proof problems

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X$ be the set of all real-valued bounded sequences. Let the function $d: X \times X \to [0,∞)$ be
$$
d(x, y) := \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\lvert x_i - y_i \rvert
$$
where $x = \{x_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}, y = \{y_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \in X$.

Show that $F = \{x \in X \mid d(x, 0) \leq 1\}$ is a bounded closed set which is not compact. Here $0$ denotes the zero constant sequence.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320619/closed-bounded-but-not-compact-subset-of-a-normed-vector-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :

1. $F=B[0,1] $ ( closed unit ball ).

Do you know in a metric space closed ball is always a closed set?

What is the definition of a bounded set? Is the diameter of $F$ finite?

2. Do you know in a metric space a set is compact iff every sequence a has subsequential limit in that set?

If so what about the sequence $(e_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}} $ where $e_n$ is sequence $1$ in the $n$-th place and zeros everywhere.

Can a sequence $(x_n) $ have a convergent subsequence sequence where $d(x_m, x_n) =1$ for $m\neq n$ ?

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. Furthermore, this question does not meet the [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).